# C++ : erase while iterating a global container

Tags: c++, stl, global

I have the following code in a function. 
`events` is a global variable:

```
map<string, map<string, deque<Event> > > events;
```

this is my function:

```
void remove_events(vector<Event> c_events)
{
  vector<Event>::iterator it1;
  deque<Event>::iterator  it2;

  for(it1 = c_events.begin(); it1 != c_events.end(); ++it1)
  {
    it2 = events[it1->device][it1->dev_id].begin();

    while(it2 != events[it1->device][it1->dev_id].end())
    {
      if(*it1 == *it2)
      {
        it2 = events[it1->device][it1->dev_id].erase(it2);
      }
      else ++it2;
    }
  }
}
```

`c_events` contains the objects I want to remove from events. However, the objects still remain in events after I tried removing them.

Let me know if you need me to post more code.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, I'm willing to bet its this... when you access a map element using `[]` notation, a key is created if it doesnt exist. So in your case, the act of checking will in fact create an item, albeit with a null value.

Comment: I check using events.size(), so I don't think thats the case

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't using [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  Here is a minimal example: http://ideone.com/MNTTOS

Comment: You'll need to run this step by step (either in a debugger or by adding print statements after small steps), and check in particular, what happens during the comparison `*it1 == *it2` -- does it yield `true` when the elements are identical, or is something going wrong there.

Comment: @Captain Obvious: Will try.

Comment: @Vaughn Cato: does it matter if I declare the global variable static or not?

Comment: It wouldn't affect whether the events get removed.  If all uses of the global variable are in the same file, then you can make it static and not put it in the header file.  If you need to use that global variable from somewhere else, you would need to define it in your source file and declare it extern in your header file.